# Why can't I match on a string or string list type

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I'm new to F# and trying to use a union type of `string` or `string list` and then match on it inside a function.

I get an error on the 2nd case that says `This expression was expected to have type 'stringOrList' but here has type ''a list'`.

I can't work out why though. Doesn't the first case match the string case and so the second would match the string list case?

```
type stringOrList = S of string | L of string list

let mockFetcher (fileOrFiles : stringOrList) url =
    match fileOrFiles with
        | S file ->
            file
        | L firstFile :: rest ->
            firstFile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, your case reads as follows: `(L firstFile) :: rest`, due to precedence rules.

It should be `L (firstFile :: rest)`

...and don't forget the missing case `L []`.

Comment: You lifesaver you. Thanks!